# How can I add a grout joint where I forgot to include one?

Tags: shower, tile, grout

I was going to grout this shower tomorrow, but I made a mistake. The shower has 3 glass corner shelves, with the tile above the shelf notched to fit over it, with 1/8" space around each shelf for grout-color-matched silicone. Somehow I managed to jam one tile right up against one shelf.

[image]

How can I carve in a grout joint here? All I can think of is drilling holes with a 1/16" masonry bit, but I'm not sure how to stop it from skating on this glazed ceramic. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: A Dremel with a diamond grit tip might do it.  Do you need full depth, or can you cheat a little just to get the appearance right?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on from that picture.  Wait a few days...maybe it won't seem like such a glaring fault.  Or, you could put the colored silicone over the tile so it looks like a grout seam.  I would try non-destructive solutions first.

Comment: Why do you think it is important that there be grout there, can't you just caulk it as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A steady hand with Dremel with a diamond grit tip might do the trick.

You go not need full depth, just enough to cosmetically apply the silicone grouth.

Comment: The glass in a shower should be tempered glass. Tempered glass is prone to breaking when struck on an edge. I'd be wary of getting near that glass edge with tools that might cause it to crack. Perhaps the glass edge could be protected with a thin piece of sheet metal while the grinding is done to minimize risk.